# check count in one to many relation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have products table that each of the product has many orders,`product.php`

```
 public function orders()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Order::class,'product_id');
  }
```

I can get products that order by order_count with this code:

```
$products = Product::withCount('orders')->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')->get();
```

Now I want to get products in controller that their orders count is bigger than 5,
How I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would to use [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```
$products = Product::withCount('orders')
    ->whereHas('orders', null, '>', 5)
    ->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

I don't think it's mentioned in the docs but you don't have to pass a closure as the 2nd param, and the 3rd and 4th can be used to pass the operator and the count.

---

Alternatively, you could use [having()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) instead:

```
$products = Product::withCount('orders')
    ->having('orders_count', '>', 5)
    ->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should give you just the orders with a count greater than 5

```
$products = Product::withCount('orders')->where('orders_count', '>', 5)->orderBy('orders_count', 'desc')->get();
```

Adding `->where()` should do it.

Hope that helps.

**Update**

Try

```
->whereRaw('count("orders.id") > 5')
```

This should work to get products with more than 5 orders.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work as you can't use aliases in where clauses, however, you could use `having()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mapping on  your collection to filter out records e.g. :`

```
    $collection = collect($products)->map(function ($product) {
                            return $product->orders->count() > 5;
                    })
                    ->reject(function ($name) {
                         return $product->orders->count() < 5;
                     });`
```

This is just an example, you can put more conditions if required.
Hope this helps.